# org-latex-export-to-pdf preamble appearing in main body

Tags: errors, export, org-mode

There appears to be a problem with how org-mode (or my configuration, maybe?) is handling latex documents. Here is the sample file that I'm trying to export:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
This is a simple paragraph at the beginning of the document. A brief introduction to the main subject.
\end{abstract}

In this document some extra packages and parameters
were added. There is an encoding package,
and pagesize and fontsize parameters.

This line will start a second paragraph. And I can
 break\\ the lines \\ and continue on a new line.

\end{document}
```

As you can see, all preamble items occur before \begin{document}, and yet when I export as a pdf, I get the following errors:

```
l.31 \documentclass
                   [12pt, letterpaper, twoside]{article}

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32 \usepackage
                [utf8]{inputenc}

! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.34 \begin{document}
                     
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (.//test.tex.aux) )
(\end occurred inside a group at level 1)

### semi simple group (level 1) entered at line 34 (\begingroup)
### bottom level
(see the transcript file for additional information) </home/josh/.texlive2017/t
exmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1000.600pk> </home/josh/.texlive2017/t
exmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecbx1000.600pk> </home/josh/.texlive2017/t
exmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1095.600pk> </home/josh/.texlive2017/t
exmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecbx1440.600pk> </home/josh/.texlive2017/t
exmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1200.600pk> </home/josh/.texlive2017/t
exmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecrm1728.600pk>
Output written on .//test.tex.pdf (1 page, 25588 bytes).
Transcript written on .//test.tex.log.
```

The document exports as a PDF, and the preamble appears under the "Contents" section, but doesn't actually affect the document. Has anyone else experienced something similar when using org-latex-export-to-pdf, or does anyone know of an alternative way of exporting this document through emacs please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [12pt, letterpaper, twoside]

#+BEGIN_abstract
This is a simple paragraph at the beginning of the document. A brief introduction to the main subject.
#+END_abstract

In this document some extra packages and parameters
were added. There is an encoding package,
and pagesize and fontsize parameters.

This line will start a second paragraph. And I can
 break @@latex:\\@@ the lines @@latex:\\@@ and continue on a new line.
```